# How can I optimize below SQL code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a stored procedure in SQL Server which uses two tables `tbPOValidation` and `tbPOValidationTemp`.

If a row of `tbPOValidationTemp` is present in `tbPOValidation`, then update `tbPOValidation` with the value from `tbPOValidationTemp`.

If it is not present, then insert the row of `tbPOValidationTemp` to `tbPOValidation`.

This SQL does that job, but I think what I am doing is not safe. In what ways can I optimise the code and make it safer so that it does the job correctly?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spPOValidation
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                  FROM tbPOValidation 
                  WHERE ShoppingCartNo IN (SELECT ShoppingCartNo 
                                           FROM tbPOValidationTemp)
                    AND LineItemNo IN (SELECT LineItemNo 
                                       FROM tbPOValidationTemp) 
                    AND PONo IN (SELECT PONo FROM tbPOValidationTemp))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tbPOValidation (SupplierName, DUNS, PONo, LineItemNo, PurchDocItemDesc, POIssueDate, DeliveryDate, PurchDocType, MtrNo,
        Location, PayTerms, BlanketNo, BlanketLineItemNo, ShoppingCartNo, SHCItmNo, ItemPricing, ItmPrcCurrency, Per, POValue, POValueCurrency,
        Qty, UOM, MFGName, MFGPartNO, Description, Remarks, Accept, AcceptedBy, AcceptedOn, RejectionReason)
            SELECT 
                SupplierName, DUNS, PONo, LineItemNo, PurchDocItemDesc, 
                POIssueDate, DeliveryDate, PurchDocType, MtrNo,
                Location, PayTerms, BlanketNo, BlanketLineItemNo, 
                ShoppingCartNo, SHCItmNo, ItemPricing, ItmPrcCurrency, Per, 
                POValue, POValueCurrency, Qty, UOM, MFGName, MFGPartNO, 
                Description, Remarks, Accept, AcceptedBy, AcceptedOn, RejectionReason 
            FROM 
                tbPOValidationTemp
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE t
        SET t.SupplierName = v.SupplierName, t.DUNS = v.DUNS, 
            t.PONo = v.PONo, t.LineItemNo = v.LineItemNo, 
            t.PurchDocItemDesc = v.PurchDocItemDesc,
            t.POIssueDate = v.POIssueDate, t.DeliveryDate = v.DeliveryDate, 
            t.PurchDocType = v.PurchDocType, t.MtrNo = v.MtrNo, 
            t.Location = v.Location, t.PayTerms = v.PayTerms, 
            t.BlanketNo = v.BlanketNo, 
            t.BlanketLineItemNo = v.BlanketLineItemNo, 
            t.ShoppingCartNo = v.ShoppingCartNo, 
            t.SHCItmNo = v.SHCItmNo, t.ItemPricing = v.ItemPricing, 
            t.ItmPrcCurrency = v.ItmPrcCurrency, t.Per = v.Per, 
            t.POValue = v.POValue, t.POValueCurrency = v.POValueCurrency, 
            t.Qty = v.Qty, t.UOM = v.UOM, t.MFGName = v.MFGName, 
            t.MFGPartNO = v.MFGPartNO, t.Description = v.Description, 
            t.Remarks = v.Remarks, t.Accept = v.Accept, 
            t.AcceptedBy = v.AcceptedBy, t.AcceptedOn = v.AcceptedOn, 
            t.RejectionReason = v.RejectionReason
        FROM
            tbPOValidation t
        JOIN 
            tbpovalidationtemp v ON t.ShoppingCartNo = v.ShoppingCartNo 
                                 AND t.LineItemNo = v.LineItemNo 
                                 AND t.PONo = v.PONo
    END

    TRUNCATE TABLE tbPOValidationTemp
END
```

Comment: It seems your `IF NOT EXISTS(...)` check is not looking for the combination of ShoppingCartNo/LineItemNo/PONo but rather the existence of the values individually. Which, if LineItemNo is a non-unique line item number in a given shopping cart (e.g. 1 thru X) then you may very well never insert missing rows for LineItemNo = 1. Have you looked into the MERGE statement [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql)

Comment: What do you mean by Not Safe?

Comment: you can use MERGE feature of sql server 2008. please refer below link - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: The part that concerns me here is the usage of a permanent "temp" table. You have a concurrency issue here that is very real. If you have two users calling this at the same time you have no way of knowing what it is in your table. And you might truncate it before the second user is finished with it. A better approach there would be to use a table valued parameter. Then you could use MERGE would be a lot simpler.

Comment: If you worry about concurrency (and you should be), read [“UPSERT” Race Condition With MERGE](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx) by Dan Guzman. It explains that you need to specify the `HOLDLOCK` hint with `MERGE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update portion will naturally limit results to those that exist, thanks to your `INNER JOIN` predicate.  You can use this same logic to re-write your insert portion with a `LEFT JOIN` for records that don't exist:

```
INSERT INTO tbPOValidation (SupplierName, DUNS, PONo, LineItemNo, PurchDocItemDesc, POIssueDate, DeliveryDate, PurchDocType, MtrNo,
                Location, PayTerms, BlanketNo, BlanketLineItemNo, ShoppingCartNo, SHCItmNo, ItemPricing, ItmPrcCurrency, Per, POValue, POValueCurrency,
                Qty, UOM, MFGName, MFGPartNO, Description, Remarks, Accept, AcceptedBy, AcceptedOn, RejectionReason)
SELECT SupplierName, DUNS, PONo, LineItemNo, PurchDocItemDesc, POIssueDate, DeliveryDate, PurchDocType, MtrNo,
           Location, PayTerms, BlanketNo, BlanketLineItemNo, ShoppingCartNo, SHCItmNo, ItemPricing, ItmPrcCurrency, Per, POValue, POValueCurrency,
           Qty, UOM, MFGName, MFGPartNO, Description, Remarks, Accept, AcceptedBy, AcceptedOn, RejectionReason 
FROM tbPOValidationTemp T
LEFT JOIN tbPOValidation T2 on T.ShoppingCartNo = T2.ShoppingCartNo
                               and T.LineItemNo = T2.LineItemNo
                               and T.PONo = T2.PONo
WHERE T2.ShoppingCartNo IS NULL --NULL filter to complete anti-join and only 
                                --insert records that do not exist
```

Then simply do your update after.  This removes all the confusing `if` logic and `in()` subqueries, and to me, is much easier to read.  Note that I am assuming you want to check for a match of `ShoppingCartNo`, `LineItemNo`, and `PONo` across a complete record, and not just check for their existence in the main table.